# PHP doesn't execute bash script when user input is multiple words

Tags: php

I'm using PHP's exec function to execute a bash script.

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   $input = $_POST['submit'];
   exec("sudo -u root sh /var/www/html/script.sh '$input'");
 }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="submit" value="">
</form>
```

As you can see, the exec command is dependent on user input. When the user's input is just one word, everything work fine and the bash script receives the input. When the user input is multiple words however, PHP does not run the exec command. The exact same command that PHP is executing works perfectly fine with multiple words when run from the command line, so it's definitely a problem with PHP.

Comment: Running a script as root with super user privileges and user input without any sanitization at all is pretty much suicide for your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `1 2 3` the result should be `1 2 3`.
Check the code below

**/var/www/html/script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in "$*"
do
   echo $i
done
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   $input = $_POST['submit'];
   print exec("sh /var/www/html/script.sh $input");
 }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="submit" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Input variable `$input` is placed in single quotes, isn't it enough to just use $1?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to test it and with your code and my script like this:

```
printf "$1\n" >> f.txt
```

it worked.
Only edition was `<input type="submit">` to submit the form.